# Does Bran still consider himself part of the Stark family?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Bran has said at least once that he's "not Brandon Stark anymore".

Yet, in the *Game of Thrones* episode "The Last of the Starks" (S08E04), when the Stark children meet in the Godswood to discuss family matters there's no question at all that he should be there. Clearly, the others still consider him their brother.

In season eight there are several instances where Sansa, Jon and Arya remind each other that they're a family.

My question is: *Does Bran ever voice something similar?*

(I'd also count references to Winterfell as his/their home or to his/their parents.)

Comment: all I get when I search up anything containing the name Bran is: Bran Stark is the Night King, Theory Explained! :/

Comment: It's very strange how they include him, but he's either out to lunch, doesn't offer much information (and really Aegon reveal is kind of destructive so far), or advice. It's like none of them get anything (they don't ask Bran any questions!) or really mean what they say about family, because essentially all of Jon's family does not support him by the episode's end. They all do not trust him and Arya just leaves never to return. Gah!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

2 points before I answer:

1. Bran is mostly the 3-Eyed Raven now so it's normal to think that he's become someone else. He mentioned last season that he remembers being Bran but is so much more now. Your quote seems a little off. Whatever part of Bran still considers himself the old Bran wouldn't express his feelings about his family mostly because he's not that kind of guy (Stark) anymore. Remember episode 4 he tells Tyrion that he doesn't feel much of anything now and that he mostly lives in the past.
2. We don't know how many strings he's pulling in the last season or if his big role was to just be bait for the night king. He knows that his physical body will be taken care of in Winterfell but I don't think his goal is to mooch. When told he's the lord of Winterfell he says, No I'm the three eye'd raven now. I think he wasn't saying "No, I'm not a Stark anymore" he was clearly saying he has another job to do now.

My answer:

Bran is no longer just Bran anymore but he is still a Stark. His home is in Winterfell with the Weirwood tree and at this point he seems to be serving the Realm of Men. That sounds pretty Stark to me, and maybe you won't ever hear him say "I love you" and/or "but we're family". But if the kid can call Jamie Lanister an "old friend" and tell Theon Greyjoy he's a "good man" theres some sort human left in him. This is just how Bran is going to communicate now as the 3-Eyed Raven.

As the 3-Eyed Raven I think he's made it pretty clear who his family is and what he considers home.

Comment: what a spot on answer

Comment: Just seen a good theory re: Bran if you've got 15mins?  https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=PWC-8qQp-qI